# Why connection to docker aspnet api + mssql db connetion failed (Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Serve)?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

may be somebody know what the problem appears. I try to start api with db conteiners but always my Fluent Migrator failed with db connection

I created the docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /src

COPY *.sln "./"
COPY ["Desk.API/Desk.API.csproj", "Desk.API/"]
COPY ["Desk.Migrations/Desk.Migrations.csproj", "Desk.Migrations/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Desk.API/Desk.API.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Desk.API"
RUN dotnet publish "Desk.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Desk.API.dll"]
```

and the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  sqldata:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=vV5r9tn0M4@
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1450:1433"

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Desk.API/docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
```

connection string

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Data Source=sqldata;Initial Catalog=Desk;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=vV5r9tn0M4@"
},
```

I always get the next exception

> fail: FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.SqlServer.SqlServer2016Processor[0]
>       There was an exception checking if table VersionInfo in (null) exists
>       Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand how fix this issue to provide correct connection

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default bridge network and you can resolve hostname in default bridge network.

[Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

You can define your own network to bypass the issue

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  sqldata:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=vV5r9tn0M4@
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1450:1433"
    networks:
      - gateway
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Desk.API/docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
    networks:
      - gateway
networks:
  gateway: {}
```

Also try removing `Persist Security Info=True` from connection string

Answer (score 0):

as the mssql default port is 1433 and the both services are on the same network (@Hans Kilian => so the first connection string should works). If the problem persist i suggest you to :

- test the connection to the mssql server using the @D-Shih configuration on port 1450 (on the host) with a client (like DBeaver)
- use your first connection (the one without the port) string on the api service
- log (if not already) the connection string before starting the application to check it's the one you want to use ?